# UPDATE local MSSQL table from Identical MySQL Linked Server Table Where Clause

Tags: mysql, sql-server, linked-server, openquery

I have two tables both named employer. One table resides on a MSSQL the other on a MySQL. The MySQL DB has been Linked.

I'm trying to update all rows in the MSSQL DB table with the data from the MySQL DB where the data is different.

Ideally, because there's so many rows, I would prefer to only UPDATE the rows that have different data.

Each DB Table has 2 Columns idemployees and employeescol1.

Below is a working sample of a script that will update ALL the rows from the Linked MySQL DB:

```
UPDATE MSSQLDB.dbo.employer
SET employeescol1 = emp2.employeescol1  
FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, 'SELECT * FROM employees') as emp2  
WHERE
   MSSQLDB.dbo.employer.idemployees = emp2.idemployee
```

How do I add a WHERE clause to say something like WHERE employeescol >= (insert variable)???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work.  You can also use synonyms, if the .... get a bit much:

```
;with cte
as
(SELECT
    *
from
   OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, 'SELECT * FROM employees')
)
UPDATE MSSQLDB.dbo.employer
SET 
    employer.employeescol1 = cte.employeescol1  
FROM
    MSSQLDB.dbo.employer 
inner join
    cte
on
    cte.idemployees = employer.idemployee
```

Comment: Excellent!! It seems to work... Question before I mark as resolved: This is a sample DB the actual DB's will have approx. 500,000 rows... I only wish to update the columns that have changed... Does the JOIN ensure this? How does the above code work exactly? The reason I ask is because when I Execute the Script it consistently displays the same amount of rows affected ie: (3 row(s) affected)

Comment: Add a where clause to the end, I.e. WHERE cte.col1 <> employer.col1 OR cte.col2 <> employer.col1 ......     (be careful of NULLS - if you think there may be any in a column, then isnull(cte.col1, '') <> isnull(employer.col, ''), etc..

Comment: What you can also do, if you want, is change it to a SELECT for the purposes of a test and see what comes back after you put the where clause in.  Then when you are happy - happy updating.  As a side-note, are there exactly the same number of records, or do you need to cater for new and/or deleted records?  If so, easy enough, just do the same query with left and right joins to see where they don't exist on either sides.  You know.

Comment: No problem.  Play around with the CTE's they are great.  The synonyms are also super useful, but remember they are server-wide.

Comment: There is a lot of this around SO.  Also subscribe to SQLCentral - daily articles - very useful.